# Скачать картинку по url - PHP

Tags: php

Есть код который работает на других сайтах, а на этом работать не хочет.

Не качает картинку по этой ссылке, а точнее качает с размером 0 байт!?

file_put_contents("img.jpg", file_get_contents("https://rezka.ag/i/2013/6/2/xfb90a40b1e10lu13v58n.jpg"));

Помогите пожалуйста скачать изображение по ссылке с этого сайта.

Answer (score -1):

Много способов..Например,

```
copy("http://rezka.ag/i/2013/6/2/xfb90a40b1e10lu13v58n.jpg","image.jpg");
```

Домен, кстати, в блоке у Ростелекома. ВПН, думаю, решит эту проблему )

UPD
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: copy - безрезультатно и ВПН не помог :(

Comment: Думаю имеет смысл выбрать другой сайт с подобной картинкой. Не думаю, что она единственная в интернете. Способ с COPY рабочий. Только что проверил.

Comment: Warning: copy(http://rezka.ag/i/2013/6/2/xfb90a40b1e10lu13v58n.jpg) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in Q:\home\test1.ru\www\test.php on line 2

Comment: Спокойно вытащил картинку с требуемого URL. Смотри выше. Помимо COPY перед ним нет никакого больше кода ? Если нет, то пробуй через CURL

Comment: > пробуй через CURL - поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на нужный CURL.

Comment: `на нужный CURL.` - а что есть разве какие-то разные курлы? Оо.

Comment: Я имел ввиду - ссылку на готовый скрипт, а вообще CURL тоже пробовал и не получилось.

Comment: Если у вас закрыт доступ к этому ресурсу, то хоть курл хоть фгетами, у вас ничего не выйдет, откройте доступы через свойства браузера (win 10) в 7ке если не ошибаюсь свойства обозревателя, точно уже не помню...и будет вам счастье.